# How do I create a TypeScript Definition file for a class whose properties change depending on instantiation

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to implement a DefinitelyTyped TS definition file for a JS class that has different definitions depending on how it's instantiated. The definitions are well defined and won't change after instantiation.
Example:

```js
var a = new MyClass("foo");
console.log(a.a);//"a"
console.log(a.b);//"b"
console.log(a.c);//"c"
console.log(a.d);//"undefined"
console.log(a.e);//"undefined"
console.log(a.f);//"undefined"

var b = new MyClass("bar");  
console.log(b.a);//"undefined"
console.log(b.b);//"undefined"
console.log(b.c);//"c"
console.log(b.d);//"d"
console.log(b.e);//"e"
console.log(b.f);//"f"
```

I'd like a TS definition something like:

```ts
interface myInterface{
    c:string;
}
class MyClass("foo") implements myInterface{
    a:string;
    b:string;
    c:string;
}
class MyClass("bar") implements myInterface{
    c:string;
    d:string;
    e:string;
    f:string;
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated
EDIT: Clarification: I cannot modify `MyClass`
Also, There is a multitude of different ways of instantiating `MyClass`, however they are all well known and defined ahead of time. We can also assume that we don't have to worry about the case of a non existant variation of `MyClass`.
Additionally, `MyClass` is best described as a factory that allows access to a database; so `new MyClass("foo")` would create an object that allows access to the *foo* table in the database, where the field names are now properties of the created `MyClass` object

Comment: If they are different, why is it the same class? Why not make two different classes?

Comment: The syntax `class MyClass("foo") implements myInterface{` is incorrect.

Comment: You're looking for the question mark (`?`), as in `d?: string;`.

Comment: Is your class instantiated only with "foo" and "bar"? What if someone passes a "car"?

Comment: @torazaburo I think the OP is searching for a way to explicitly change the type of the class depending on the instantiation, not just have all members optional.

Comment: @torazaburo, Alex is correct. I was using that as an example. I realize it is incorrect, but shows the end effect I am looking for.

YK1, We can assume this is a nonissue.

Answer (score -1):

**If you have control over the code...**

You should consider fixing it. What you describe is two different types, it does not make much sense to have a class change it's type depending on the input parameters.

The `MyClass` in your example looks like some kind of odd factory that uses the constructor instead of a method to create objects.

A solution in code could look something like this using union types and type guards:

```
class Foo {
    public FooMember: string = "I'm foo";
}

class Bar {
    public BarMember:string = "I'm bar";
}

let myObj: Foo | Bar;

myObj = new Foo(); // or FooBarFactory.GetInstance("Foo") or whatever

if(myObj instanceof Foo){
    console.log(myObj.FooMember);
} else {
    console.log(myObj.BarMember);
}
```

**If you don't have control over the code...**

...you are basically out of luck, in regards of having it typed differently depending on the input to the constructor. You can not type the constructor of a class to return anything other than the type of the class.